Can pgn-extract find sequences of moves in the middle of the game?
I see that pgn-extract can search for variations in games, but all of the examples in the documentation show variations from the starting position. What if I wanted to look for variations in the middle of the game, say I want to find games where the following sequence has been played at any given time in the game:
Bxf7+ Kxf7 Ng5+
I don't see a good way to do this. I see the --startply flag, but I wasn't sure if it looks exactly after the ply it's asked to start at, or at all sequences after that ply. Either way, I couldn't get it to work in a sensible way under either interpretation, so I'm not sure that's the answer.

You can use CQL.

Thanks for the link, had never heard of that.

No problem. If you encounter any issues, you can always post a new question here.

The short answer is that pgn-extract cannot do that. However, it would be an interesting feature to add, so feel free to email me to discuss it as a future addition.

I am sorry if you didn't like my approach to this one. pgn-extract is my software (albeit open source). So, it was a genuine offer to add the functionality if the OP wanted me to add it to a future release. My feeling is that that sort of discussion of requirements is better had via email rather than in a forum like this.
The concrete answer was that pgn-extract can't currently do that :)
